# SQL Server 2008 forgets my login and password

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

For some reason SQL Server 2008 (Management Studio) refuses to remember my username and password for a specific server instance even though I've checked "remember password" probably hundreds of times when logging in successfully, until now when I've just had it.

The username and password for any other instance is remembered correctly, but this one just refuses to. In fact it seems that *no* settings are remembered for this particular connection.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a local instance of SSMS?  What version (enterprise, express, etc)?

Comment: It's all express (with \SQLEXPRESS). The server instance is not local, but the SSMS instance is.

Comment: I think this is a same question with below one.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659384/why-does-ms-sql-mgmt-studio-express-keep-forgetting-my-passwords